# ModelState errors don't show in partial view form

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a part of a form in a partial view. The form is partly reusable in different pages:

Page 1 (with CompanyId):

```
<form method="post">
    <partial name="_partialForm" model="Model.MyModel" />
    <input asp-for="CompanyId />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Page 2 (without CompanyId):

```
<form method="post">
    <partial name="_partialForm" model="Model.MyModel" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

_partialForm:

```
@model Models.MyModel

<label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
<input asp-for="FirstName />
<span asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
<label asp-for="LastName"></label>
<input asp-for="LastName />
<span asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
```

MyModel:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("First name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[Required]
[DisplayName("Last name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; }
```

When I look at the source of the rendered page, the `label asp-for`-values are there and the `input`-fields are decorated with `data-val="true" data-val-required="Required"`, so the binding is OK.

When I post the form, I check `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` and if not `return Page()`.

The result is, if FirstName or LastName is empty, that ModelState isn't valid, but no validation messages are shown.

If I move the form-tag to the partial view (meaning I cannot keep the CompanyId-field as it shall only be available on a single page), the validation errors shows.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: where is the action name specified in form attribute?

Comment: <form method="post"> should be like: <form method="post" action="" controller="">

Comment: check the rendered controls name attribute value in rendered HTML, is it actual name or actual name append with partialview name. Model Binder exactly check the name attribute value from control with the model property, both should match.

Comment: @NomiAli there's none, meaning it is submitted to the same page (it's Razor pages: OnGet() / OnPost())

Comment: Change  `<partial name="_partialForm" model="Model.MyModel" />` to  `<partial name="_partialForm" model="@Model.MyModel" />`.

Comment: @NomiAli the names should match. I get (not shown in the example) `asp-label-for` values showed correctly. It's only the ModelState errors that's missing

Comment: @mxmissile just tried that. Doesn't make any difference

Comment: check browser > "inspect element" and check the name of rendered controls for FirstName, LastName controls. check how the form is rendering as html. Paste the rendered HTML here in question.

Comment: @NomiAli I've updated the question a little. Please read it again to better understand the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, we are not talking about client-side validation right? You would not hit the `OnPost` method if that was the case.

Comment: Have you included the `_ValidationScriptsPartial` in the page?

Comment: What is the value of `ModelState.IsValid` in your `OnPost`? I just tried your code, and it works as expected, however I could not hit OnPost without FirstName LastName data. Are you missing `[BindProperty]` on your Model.MyModel property?

Comment: @mxmissile no, it's not client side - and yes, I have the [BindProperty] too. The strange thing is, that if I move the form-tag into the partial view everything works.

Comment: @NomiAli I still have this problem. A strange thing is, that when I look at the source, the binding name is FirstName, but if I do a foreach on the ModelState keys in the partial view, it says MyModel.FirstName. And again, if I move the form-tag into the partial view, the binding/errorchecking works as expected.

Comment: Solved! The solution was to do `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "MyModel";` in the partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to do ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "MyModel"; in the partial.